# If $\mathcal{I}(X) = (f)$ then $X$ is irreducible if and only if $f$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\scrI}{\mathcal{I}}$
$\newcommand{\scrV}{\mathcal{V}}$
$\newcommand{\scrO}{\mathscr{O}}$
$\newcommand{\A}{\mathbb{A}}$
**Context:** Here we're considering the Zariski topology, we denote $\scrO(\A^n) = k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$; i.e the collection of all regular maps defined on $\A^n \rightarrow k$. The field $k$ is infinite and algebraically closed. The maps $\scrI$ and $\scrV$ denote the maps from the Nullstellensatz, i.e $\scrI$ carries algebraic sets to the ideal of all polynomials vanishing on the entire set, and $\scrV$ carries ideals to the subset of affine space which vanish every polynomial in the ideal. An algebraic set $X$ is said to be **reducible** if $X = Y \cup Z$ where $Y,Z$ are proper algebraic subsets of $X$.

**Problem:**  Suppose that $\scrI(X) = (f)$ for some $f \in \scrO(\A^n)$. Show that $X$ is irreducible if and only if $f$ is irreducible in $\scrO(\A^n)$.

I think I have one direction down, but it's the other that's giving me issue. For refernce, here is the attempt.

> *Attempt:* To prove the forward direction we prove the contrapositive, i.e $f$ reducible implies that $X$ is reducible.  If $f$ is reducible then $f = gh$ for some $g,h \notin \scrO(\A^n)^\times = k\setminus \{0\}$. Because neither $g$ or $h$ is a unit, we know that $(g)$ and $(h)$ are not the entire ring $\scrO(\A^n)$. We know that $(gh) = (g)(h)$, i.e the product ideal of the principal ideals, so that $\scrI(X) = (f) = (gh) = (g)(h)$. By the Nullstellensatz, since $X$ is algebraic $\scrV(\scrI(X)) = X$ and so $X = \scrV((g)(h))$, which by the properties of vanishing sets is just $\scrV(g) \cup \scrV(h)$. We also know that $X = \scrV(f)$, moreover because $f = gh$ we know that $(f) \subset (g)$ and $(f) \subset (h)$. The contravariance of $\scrV$ gives that $\scrV(g) \subset \scrV(f)$ and $\scrV(h) \subset \scrV(f)$ and we conclude that $X = \scrV(g) \cup \scrV(h)$ is a reducible decomposition of $X$.

I'm having trouble showing the reverse direction. If $f$ is irreducible, what does that tell me about $X$? I know $\scrI(X) = (f)$ so if $f = gh$ where one has to be a unit, say wlog $h$, it follows that $\scrI(X) = (g)(h) = (g)\scrO(\A^n) = (g)$. But what does this give? Then $X = \scrV(g)$, but how can I then show this is irreducible? Thanks in advance for the hint, and if you could let me know if the first direction could be done faster I'd appreciate it. This was a 2 liner example in a book, so I might be missing an easy solution.

Comment: Have you tried assuming $X$ is reducible? (Existence is usually a more useful assumption than non-existence is) Where did that attempt get stuck?

Comment: Caveat: Why do you know that $f$ is not a square, i.e. $f=gh$ with $g=h$? I believe there is something missing from your current argument regarding this situation.

Comment: Well if I start from there $X = Y \cup Z$ where $Y,Z$ are proper closed subsets of $X$. Then $X =\mathcal{V}(IJ)$ where $IJ$ are the ideals generated by the polynomial sets defining $Y$ and $Z$. This gives $\mathcal{I}(X) = \mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(IJ)) = (f)$. This would also give $\mathcal{V}(f) = Y \cup Z$ but I don't see where to go from there. Do I pick distinct elements of $Y$ and $Z$? Maybe carry them back to $\mathcal{I}(\{x\})$ and $\mathcal{I}(\{y\})$? @BrianMoehring

Comment: Well in the direction I have I assume that $f$ is reducible so that it does have two unique non-unit factors no? Just by definition? @student91

Comment: Reducible means it has two factors, these need not be distinct. e.g. $x_1^2$ is reducible, because $x_1^2=x_1\cdot x_1$.

Comment: Ah ok fair. Well then in that case the decomposition wouldn't work. I don't quite know how to fix that right now.

Comment: @IrvingRabin With regard to student91's point.  Go back to the definition of $\mathcal{I}$.  You're working over a field, so if $(g(P))^n=0$ then $g(P)=0$, so $\mathcal{I}(X)$ is radical.